# Questions and help regarding the implementation of Quartz.net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, scheduler, quartz.net-2.0

I am trying to write a simple proof of concept application implementing Quartz.net 2.x. I have never seen such poor excuse for documentation. I have so many questions that I can't seem to get answered. It seems that the documentation assumes that you have been using version 1.x and are migrating to 2.x (actually a good portion of the 2.x tutorial is 1.x specific.) Well, I've never used the Java based Quartz, Quartz.net 1.x, and obviously not 2.x. So I will try to lay my question(s) out as organized as I can. An answer to any of them or direction to documentation, a tutorial, etc. would be most welcome.

- Ultimately I simply want to implement Quart.net 2.0 to fire any trivial job (embedded. not a service.)

  1. What is structure of the job that Quartz.net executes? A method, class, etc? It seems that it is a class, but I can't seem to find a definitive answer to this question.
  2. Can someone explain what a Factory, Store, and Datamap are and when they should be used?
  3. What's up with the XML? Some tutorial show XML being used... some don't. When and why would I use XML?

I'll stop there for now. I hope someone has the time to help me through this. I would be very much grateful. While code is always helpful, I am more interested in understanding the process. I will need to use Quartz.net in future projects.

Comment: I used Quartz.Net about two years ago and found that going through the tutorials gives you everything you need to start: http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/

Comment: Hi W0lf. The link you posted is for Java. I am using .net, more specifically C#. And the tutorial you read was probably for quartz 1.0 which is implemented differently than 2.0. While I'm not above learning 1.0 first, it seems irritatingly arduous to learn an old technology to use a newer version. Thanks for the answer either way.

Comment: you're right; the above link is not for Quartz.NET. I meant this one: http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Yeah, that is the tutorial I was talking about. It is linked from 2.0 but it is actually over 1.0. Pretty irritating. I wish I could find something decent for 2.0 that explained things in detail. Thanks again for the reply.

Comment: Considering how much you are paying for the documentation, one could say it's adequate. As an open source project you are always free to contribute by writing more of it. There's also an example project that comes with the distribution that is loaded with samples.

Comment: Marko, it's pretty difficult to contribute documentation for something that you don't and can't understand. As for the samples, like the rest of this is experience, they are broken. I did manage to get them working with the aid of another, more experience developer. What a mess this experience has been. And, Marko, after seeing that you are the project lead of Quartz.net, I am a little dismayed that you took the time to comment but didn't answer a single question or point to any good sources to get them answered. I would have loved to get some quality input from the guru himself.

Comment: @MarkoLahma There is no ability to edit or correct the documentation or even post comments against it. If I'm wrong, please let me know how the documentation can be edited by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, for anyone looking for documentation, the best I could find was the Java documentation that W0lf has linked in the comments. Since Quartz.net is a port of the Java version, the documentation is similar enough to begin to understand some of the inner workings. I am developing some simple jobs to test and gain experience. Hopefully, I can contribute something to the community at some point.

Found another great place for information. The timeline starts by using 1.0 but then migrates to 2.0. But there is great info there and I can't thank the author enough for his work. Here's a link: http://jvilalta.blogspot.com

On another note, I was a little harsh on Marko Lahma. He is helping to provide an open source product that we can all use. I can't think him and his team enough for that. I do have a peeve when it comes to help requests though. It takes as much time to answer a question as it does to critique it. Why not just answer the question? Anyway, Marko, I apologize for being brash. However, finding time to update your documentation would be extremely helpful. I will contribute what I can as I can.

Comment: I think your estimate that you were a "little harsh" is very much an understatement. All the questions you asked were completely answered in that Quartz.net 1.x tutorial and are still relevant for 2.x.

Comment: Dean, had "All the questions you asked were completely answered Quartz.net 1.x tutorial and are still relevant for 2.x" been said it would had saved a lot of trouble. Based on 2 things, I assumed that the documentation for 1.x is outdated with respect to 2.x. First, the migration page specifically says "significant changes to the API" and second, my first attempt at implementation found that the JobDetail class (which is on the first page of the 2.x tutorial) didn't exist within the 2.x libraries. I stand behind not wasting time bashing a poster rather than answer the question.